# $F(h)=\int_0^1{h\left\lvert f(x+h)-f(x) \right\rvert}dx$ has derivative at 0

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

> Let $f$ be a Riemann integrable function defined on $[-2,2]$. Define a function
>   $F:(-1,1)\to \Bbb{R}$ by $$F(h)=\int_0^1{h\left\lvert f(x+h)-f(x) \right\rvert}dx$$
>   Show that the derivative $F'(0)$ exists.

I have tried to use the fundamental theorem of calculus after some change of variables, but it doesn't seem to work since there is no relation between $h$ and $x$.

Then I tried to prove by definition: proving the following limit exists
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(h)-F(0)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\int_0^1{\left\lvert f(x+h)-f(x) \right\rvert}dx$$
I guess the limit is $0$. But I don't know how to prove it. Could you please give me some hints? Thank you.

**Edit:** Well, after some trying, I think I can do it like this (a rough idea):
$$\left\lvert f(x+h)-f(x) \right\rvert\le \underset{P_h}{\sup f}-\underset{P_h}{\inf f}$$ where $P_h$ is a partition of $[-2,2]$ s.t. it has some relation to restrict the $\left\lvert f(x+h)-f(x) \right\rvert$ to be small enough. I think this is the right approach, how can I change it to a rigorous argument?

Comment: Use Lebesgue criterion for Riemann integrability. Here discontinuities of $f$ form a set of measure zero. Hence the difference $|f(x + h) - f(x)|$ is mostly small when $h$ is small except for some values of $x$ lying in a set of measure zero. Thus we can choose a partition $P$ of $[0, 1]$ where the subintervals where "this difference is not small" have a small total length and in rest of sub-intervals the difference is small. Thus the overall integral is small and derivative $F'(0) = 0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh is it so important to have a 1-dimensional interval here? Isn't $\lim_{h \to 0}\int_A |f(x+h)-f(x)|=0$ also for any $f \in L^1( \mathbb R^n)$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh my comment was wrongly worded, check the update

Comment: @MarcoDisce: The result which you mention is true but not so obvious and self-evident. In fact the current question demands the proof of this result for Riemann integrable functions. Also note that we don't need any details of Lebesgue integrals here. Only the criterion of Riemann integrability in terms of discontinuities being a set of measure zero is required.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh ok but what if the same question was made for a Riemann integrable function on $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @MarcoDisce: The same reasoning applies in 2d also. We need 2d partitions where each sub-interval is actually a small rectangle. The same criteria of Riemann integrability holds namely that discontinuities must form a set of measure zero.

Comment: It's a shame about the absolute value in the integrand; without it there's a cute elementary proof....

Comment: what is the elementary proof?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is **no absolute value** inside the integral, i.e., that
$$
F(h) = \int_{0}^{1} h\bigl(f(x + h) - f(x)\bigr)\, dx,
$$
here's a short, elementary proof.

For $|h| < 1$, you have
$$
\int_{0}^{1} f(x + h)\, dx = \int_{h}^{1 + h} f(x)\, dx,
$$
i.e., "the integral of the same function over a shightly shifted interval". Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, its absolute value is bounded on $[-2, 2]$ by some real number $M$, so
\begin{align*}
\left\lvert \frac{F(h) - F(0)}{h}\right\rvert
  &= \left\lvert\int_{0}^{1} \bigl(f(x + h) - f(x)\bigr)\, dx\right\rvert \\
  &= \left\lvert\int_{h}^{1 + h} f(x)\, dx - \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\, dx\right\rvert \\
  &= \left\lvert\int_{1}^{1 + h} f(x)\, dx - \int_{0}^{h} f(x)\, dx\right\rvert
  \leq 2M|h|.
\end{align*}

---

**With the absolute value**, it looks to me that Paramanand Singh is right: You need that $f$ is "almost uniformly continuous".

Here's a workable strategy: Approximate $f$ by a *continuous* function $g$ with $\int_{-2}^{2} |f(x) - g(x)|\, dx$ small (this is a little delicate, but elementary enough to be an exercise in Spivak's *Calculus*, if memory serves). Then use uniform continuity of $g$ to show
$$
\int_{0}^{1} |g(x + h) - g(x)|\, dx
$$
can be made arbitrarily small by taking $|h|$ sufficiently small. Finally, triangle inequality and the standard algebraic trick
$$
f(x + h) - f(x)
  = \bigl[f(x + h) - g(x + h)\bigr]
  + \bigl[g(x + h) - g(x)\bigr]
  + \bigl[g(x) - f(x)\bigr]
$$
can be used to control
$$
\int_{0}^{1} |f(x + h) - f(x)|\, dx.
$$

Comment: The approximation via continuous $g$ was a good one (and yes! your memory serves right, the existence of continuous $g$ as an approximation to integrable $f$ is an exercise from Spivak). That way one can avoid the direct use of Lebesgue criterion of Riemann integrability. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thank you for checking the reference. :) Lebesgue's criterion was my first thought, as well, but if $f$ is continuous off a set $E$ of small measure, one has to handle the vexing possibility that $x \in E$ and $x + h \not\in E$, or _vice versa_. I think this is doable, but approximating by a continuous function seemed cleaner.